# Nextjs app router layout/template cache not evicted

Tags: reactjs, caching, next.js

I'm migrating a nextjs webapp to the new app folder structure with nextjs 13.4 version and I'm having an issue I don't know how to fix it. The flow is the following:

1. A user goes to login page and logs in successfully. A cookie is created with the session info.
2. Is then redirected to home page.
3. The home page has a `layout` where the session info is loaded from the cookie and pass it to a client component header to load the logged in menu.
4. The header does not shows the logged in menu because the layout is cached.

I tried to use `revalidatePath` function but seems to not work, also I tried to add a `template` which seems the solution for this problem and it is also not working.

How can I load the cookie session and show the header correctly in the layout/template? Here is an example repo: https://github.com/soasada/next134